# Unable to refresh data from sharepoint list in excel services

Tags: excel, data, refresh

I've a SharePoint farm with Excel Application Services configured.
I've created a Excel workbook with OData connection to SharePoint list.
In Excel web view, I can't refresh data.

Need help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to make use of the Secure Store Service in order to do that.

Make sure the "Excel" Target Application in the Secure Store Services Application has all the desired members including yourself in the Members list.

Also, make sure the Authentication Settings is set to None or the SSS, not the authenticated account. This is under the Excel workbook -> Data -> Connections -> Properties of the DataConnection -> Definition -> Authentication Settings

Comment: Done it ! The error is about another data connection : a datamodel called ThisWorkbookDataModel

Comment: Excel can't refresh this datamodel.

Comment: Make sure the credential using the Excel Unattended account has access to view the web application fully, and also make sure the "Members" of the SSS target application that uses the excel unattended account includes all users.

Comment: Done it ! same error !

Comment: I have done the same thing but I'm still having the same issue.. can someone please help me? I have configured unattended account and set the connection string to none but I still get an error occurred in the data model.